# download a jar from maven repository to a local directory

Tags: java, maven-3

How to download a jar from central repository to a local directory. I'm using maven 3.04

I used following command

mvn dependency:get -X -DrepoUrl={url} -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:LATEST -DoutputDirectory=$(pwd)

the jar is being downloaded into local repository , .m2 directory but not to the directory specified.

I tried using mvn dependency:copy but it asks for a pom.xml which I don't want to write

Comment: Just add is as a dependency to your pom than it will be downloaded automatically. Yes you have to write a pom file...

Answer (score 0):

[`dependency:get`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) has `-Ddest` instead of `-DoutputDirectory` option, but it's deprecated with a note that you should use `dependency:copy`.

[`dependency:copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) works fine without pom.xml, you just need to provide it all required parameters, e.g.:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 -DoutputDirectory=.
```